# Need advice. SRM Origin alu vs Quarq Dfour

Tags: power, road

I am road cyclist willing to participate in local cycling races. I am looking forward to buying a new powermeter. Currently I have 4iiii left crank  only and I want more accurate device to be more confident in data. My best 20 min power is 317 watts and I see some room for improvements as I am 24 y.o. and I'm doing road cycling for 2nd year so far. I have canyon tt bike and mid-range road bike. Currently for tt races I swap crankset between 2 bikes which I find annoying.

I am looking for options to get new powermeter (maybe for tt bike only) as I am going to do dedicated tt workouts. For now based on recommendations I know that I want crankset based powermeter (neither pedals nor cranks) and descent options I see are SRM and Quarq.

I've made this table for comparison:[image]

As there are very few reviews available for SRM Origin alu or Quarq, I am asking for piece of advice.

Is quarq accuracy descent enough that price difference can be neglected?

Are quarq carbon cranks way better that alu cranks from srm? I have no experience with carbon cranks.

If choosing quarq it will be ultegra chainrings most likely as 20 gramms dont value 60 eur but dura ace is there just for contrast.

Comment: "For now based on recommendations I know that I want crankset based powermeter (neither pedals nor cranks) " - I think you want a **chainring**-based PM, as opposed to a crank**arm**-based PM. Is this correct?

Comment: @WeiwenNg not chainring-based exactly, but spider-based. Based on what I know - it gives most accurate readings of left-right balance and data comes from single device instead of two different crankarms.

Comment: There are also pedal-based powermeters but only with Look-roadtype cleats.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, Vladyslav. Unfortunately, Stack Exchange isn't the site for specific product recommendations. You have to make the tradeoffs regarding stated accuracy and price yourself. My opinion would be to just go with the Quarq, since they are very well regarded.